# CakePHP default layout, can't pass values to default.ctp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have one page website, on homepage(Layout/default.ctp) I have 2 forms, subscribe and contact form that are being controlled over contact controller. With $this->set('some_val', 'test'); I can set value from AppController, but not from contact controller, how can I set values from contact controller to be available in default.ctp except with sessions?

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    //pr('beforeFilter'); // i was testing is this happening or not
    //exit();
    $tester = 'test';
    $this->set(compact('tester'));
}
```

and in default.ctp I just pr($this->viewVars); to make sure that I have tester value, but it is always empty.

Is this right approach how to implement several controllers in one page design?

Another question is there a place/function where I could check is current request post or not, I would like to check for each request what is it?

Thank you.

Comment: please paste some more of your codes or explain properly what you want

Comment: @Learner There is no more code except 2 functions in Contact controller that are relevant, you have above several questions.

Comment: You are misusing the framework. You should just make your homepage `/contact/:action` and then you'd just edit the form action to post the to each controller.

Comment: Why is `CakeSession` not a possibility? Could you elaborate more on that? because don't understand why you'd want do anything else in `Default.ctp` then session-control for authentication purposes.

Comment: also dont use beforeFilter() if not absolutely necessary - to set data to the controller beforeRender() is the right way to go since it is triggered after possible redirects have been made and the layout will actually be rendered and will need what you pass down.

Comment: @DavidYell Hi ,thank you, it make sense, but how to handle my homepage now when I have 2 different controllers in it?

Comment: @Ariaan I have just one page, it is single page design, now with 2 different contollers in it, that is the reason I'm using default layout, I'm not cakeph developer, so I'm maybe wrong. CakeSession are fine, and great solution, I have stored in session validation errors, and just display them in page(when there are no validation errors I have delete these sessions), problem was that sometimes when I refresh page, validation errors are still there, they are not being destroyed.

Comment: @mark I do not have view for contact controller, I'm using default.ctp, try to die in beforeRender if you do not have view to see why I'm using beforeFilter.

Comment: as the others said: you should have a view for it!

Comment: Basically you shouldn't have two controllers. You need to read the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but it sounds like you might need multiple layouts:

```
class CarsController extends AppController
{
  public function index($page)
  {
    /* Your logic */

    if ( $page == 'other' ) {
      $this->render('view', 'layout');
    } else {
      $this->render('view-other', 'layout-other');
    }
  }
}
```

For more information i'd suggest looking at: http://api20.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-Controllerrender

Comment: Hi Render was a function that needed me, tnx.

Comment: Hope you figure out that part about multiple controllers, since that would be physically impossible :P, thx for the upvote! :)

Comment: yes, I have google out other problem, I'm new at cakephp, no problem for upvote, render really help me. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

try an echo $tester; in your default, it should be available.

If the request is post, you would have data in $this->data.

Comment: Hi, pr($this->viewVars) should also display $tester, but it is not displaying because it is not being set, $this->data will work just from controller that data is being sent to, not for default.ctp(my homepage), it would be great if I could catch every single request, to check is it post or not.

Comment: What is the end result you are trying to get. Why are you trying to set vars in the beforeFilter.